# Hearing capability in audio player

Tags: speed, player

Do you have any recommendation regarding the speed a human can hear audio and still understand?

In my app I'm using ticks of 0.1 between X 0.5 - 2.

- is it too granular ?
- what speeds should I offer that are reasonable for hearing

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Speaking as a user here)
Having been listening to audiobooks daily for over a decade, I can tell from personal experience that it depends heavily on the speaker. Some are still very clear at x1.8, and others begin to get blurry at 1.3. Of course, depends on the listener as well.

I don't think it's too granular - my favorite audiobook player has the same level of granularity and I find it to be very useful.
(/user)

The speeds you should provide depend on the use cases, I could imagine use cases where speeds higher than 2 are still useful, e.g. for skimming over a long recording, without the need to understand exactly what's being said, but waiting for a specific identifiable segment. Like "searching" within a lecture that you've attended, or an interview.